# Apache not restarting, getting segmentation fault. Tried solutions but not working

Tags: apache, apache2, apache2.4

I started my laptop after almost a month. Accessing `localhost` is giving me below error:

```
apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2017-08-21 20:13:20 GST; 1min 9s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 11127 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 11110 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 21 20:13:20 user-HP-ProBook-6470b systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Apache2 web server.
Aug 21 20:13:20 user-HP-ProBook-6470b systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
Aug 21 20:13:20 user-HP-ProBook-6470b apache2[11110]:  * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2
Aug 21 20:13:20 user-HP-ProBook-6470b apache2[11110]: Segmentation fault
Aug 21 20:13:20 user-HP-ProBook-6470b apache2[11110]: Action 'start' failed.
Aug 21 20:13:20 user-HP-ProBook-6470b apache2[11110]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Aug 21 20:13:20 user-HP-ProBook-6470b apache2[11127]:  * Stopping Apache httpd web server apache2
Aug 21 20:13:20 user-HP-ProBook-6470b apache2[11127]:  *
Aug 21 20:13:20 user-HP-ProBook-6470b systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with following Apache2 version:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2016-07-14T12:32:26
```

I tried changing `httpd.conf` as mentioned in other articles, but that didn't helped and I still continue to get this error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Segmentation fault is caused by illegal memory access which usually causes unmasked interrupt and core dump to be stored in disk and terminating the process, have you tried to use ulimit with apache ? have you examined the core dump of the crash ? have you tried to troubleshoot it with strace ? can you please post some of your findings as this needs more data to be troubleshooted.

Comment: @AbdullahShahin - Sure, I can do what you have mentioned. Can you provide some link or guide on how to perform the mentioned things?